# PHP comparison operator don't work in angular 8 app

Tags: php, conditional-statements, comparison, angular8

I am working on a school project. 
The client-side is in Angular 9, and the server-side is PHP, made with SlimFramework v3.
The login function in my php backend:

Controller.php

```
$app->post('/api/user/login', function(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response) use ($app){
   $data = $request->getParsedBody();
   $email = $data['email_json'];
   $password = $data['password_json'];
   $freg = new FRegistrazione();
   $res = $freg->login($email, $password);
   if ($res = true){
    $secretKey = "Ma69r3Ga8A";
    $issuerClaim = "APACHESERVER";
    $audienceClaim = "CINEMA";
    $issuedatClaim = time();
    $notbeforeClaim = $issuedatClaim + 10;
    $expireClaim = $issuedatClaim + 60000;
    $token = array(
        "iss" => $issuerClaim,
        "aud" => $audienceClaim,
        "iat" => $issuedatClaim,
        "nbf" => $notbeforeClaim,
        "exp" => $expireClaim,
        "data" => array(
            "email" => $email,
            "password" => $password));
    $jwt = JWT::encode($token, $secretKey);
    $response = json_encode(
            array(
                "res" => "ok",
                "message" => "Login eseguito correttamente",
                "jwt" => $jwt,
                "email" => $email,
                "exipireAt" => $expireClaim
    ));
   } else {
       $response = json_encode(
            array(
                "res" => "ko",
                "message" => "Credenziali  errate"
    ));}
   return $response;
   });
```

Class FRegistrazione.php

```
    public function login($email, $password) {
        $islogged = false;
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM registrazione WHERE email = ' . '\'' . $email . '\'' . ' AND password = ' . '\'' . $password . '\'';
        $res = $this->_connection->query($query);
        if ($res->num_rows == 1) {
    $islogged = true;} else {$islogged = false;}
```

This code works correctly if I send a request with Postman.
But when I send a login request from Angular9,

```
if ($res->num_rows == 1) {
    $islogged = true;} else {$islogged = false;}
```

always returns `$islogged=false`, even in the case of a valid query on Mysql.

Comment: = is not a comparison, you want ==. `if ($res = true){` will always be true since you are setting $res to true. You probably meant `if ($res == true){`.

Comment: Hi Dave, in this post there is an error, excuse me. However, I tried with the ==, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What error? Please always indicate exact error messages. Also, it is possible you have 2 errors in your code. Dave's comment is correct, you should use `==` or `===` in your if statement. Unless you're intending to make an assignment, in which case you should not use an `if`.

Comment: Hi SherylHohman, the code in the question contains an error of transcription. I already use the ($res == true) assignment in my project, but it don't work with either solutions who Dave recomended me. I don't understand why if make a POST request with Postman, the code work perfectly, but the same code don't work by a POST request with angular App, In details, it seems that it doesn't support the if statement. Thank you too SherylHohman for your attention.

Comment: Hi to all, I have just resolved my issue, a JSON encode of my variables from the client-side created a interference with the quotation marks of my query, and the mysqli method returned null. I decoded these variables, the quotation marks don't creates 
misunderstanding and the code work correctly. Thank you very much.